# Einstein Search not working as expected

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, einstein, search

We have enabled Einstein Search in our org, but when I search of "My open Cases" it's showing as the old search result.

I referred to this article.

https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2019/09/introducing-einstein-search.html

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question with the information provided, but there are actually 2 separate enablement processes. It's common to just do one and believe that you have all of Einstein Search when in fact you haven't enabled all the features. It's also common to miss one of the steps within an enablement process. Below is a summary as of March 5, 2020. The process may change, so if that doesn't work check documentation and help, or contact Salesforce support.

Personalization feature:
In the setup dialog box, search for Einstein Search, then look under search setup, and enable the checkbox. This will turn it on for the entire org.

Einstein Search UI and Natural Language search: create a new permission set, assign the Einstein Search license to it, and within this permission set under system permissions, enable the 3 features available. Once that is completed, assign the pemrission set to those users that you would like to have access to Einstein Search.

It may, of course, be a completely different issue, in which case you should contact the product team via the info below. (yes, I'm from the product team)

For more info you can email EinsteinSearch@salesforce.com, or sign up to get in contact with the product team here: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdWGlkZd8tSjXTNvKe_Qf_qrm_XOsqQNm9NwZJLMhXPp2DuSg/viewform?usp=pp_url

Comment: Hi Chris, are you on the product team? If so, would you mind calling that out in your answer so the Stack Exchange community understands where you're coming from?